# Issues with faces on an object - Blender 2.93

Tags: faces

So I have a plane and for some reason some faces of the plane will show filled from side but not the other.(Also the circles are not a part of the plane). I'm so confused as to why this is happening. This happened after I did Mesh -> Clean up -> Merge by distance. Before that the faces showed as filled on both sides. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello please share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Try selecting all in Edit mode and SHIFT-N > Recalculate Normals. No idea about the circles without seeing the Blend file.

Comment: @moonboots is pasteall the new preferred over blend-exchange?  I'm getting errors uploading with blend-exchange today and often.  The du jour error: " There was an internal error attempting to complete your request. "

Comment: @james_t Yes, it looks like there's a problem, I don't know what's happening. Pasteall is not the "official" alternative host site, it's just that it has been asked not to clutter Blend-Exchange, not sure it's better to cluster pasteall though